# I want to create multiple excel sheets in a single excel file using the elements from 'number' as their name

Tags: python, excel

```py
import pandas as pd

number=['200','300','400','500']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

for n in number:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='') #Here i want to add the elements for 'number' list as 
                                         sheet name
    

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

For above, my understanding is that you want to add 4 worksheets to the file multiple.xlsx file with names as in array n.
if you need the data along with the index column to be added, then use this for the for loop.

```
for n in number:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=n)
```

If you don't want the index numbers to be added to the tables, use this code.

```
for n in number:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=n, index=False)
```

You will get 4 tabs with the df1 data as shown below (screenshot for second case)

[image]